# How can I make Raphael JS faster in IE 11?

Tags: raphael

I've inherited a Javascript application that has uses Raphael JS to draw a diagram.  Drawing the diagram contributes very substantially to the loading time of the application.  I thought that since the diagram is never scaled and is drawn exactly the same time each time the page loads, it might make sense to render the diagram as a simple raster image.  However, this doesn't work because mouse events are attached to the individual figures within the diagram.

Looking thru the code, I see that it consists of repeated calls to `Raphael.path`.

Unfortunately, for reasons beyond my control, my users are constrained to use IE 11.

Is there some practical way that I can make the application render the diagram faster?  Is there perhaps some practical way to serialize the result of calling `Raphael.path` repeatedly so that the user doesn't have to wait for these operations at every page load?

Comment: I guess it depends if you want the users to wait until the paths are drawn or not...

Comment: Actually, the paths are not visible from where the users initially land on the page.  Is it possible to draw the paths asynchronously?

Comment: I would have thought so, maybe put up the code you tried to make it async and didn't work.